# I accidentaly changed the URL on a teamsite

Tags: url, access

I changed the URL on a team site from Site settings - Title, description and logo and now I have lost access to the site. How can I get this access back?

Comment: changed from where??

Comment: From Site settings - Title, description and logo

Answer (score 0):

You changed the url of a subsite, that is all. All other permissions and such are the same. You simply need to navigate to the new url, go to Site settings - Title, description and logo and change it back to the previous url.